# In CSS, how is the "height" computed for block element?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Below is an example

```css
div > span {
  font-size: 10em;
}
div {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

/* Normalize the default font size */
body {
  font-size: 16px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Cat</span>
</div>
```

When I inspected the height of `div` element in Chrome or Safari, its computed value of `height` is 66px.

However, the `66px` looks a magic number for me, as I have no idea how this value is computed. I searched for this topic on Google but didn't find a good document which can explain the computation clearly.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: I don't know about that 66, but probably that value is going to change between different browser, because it all depends on the default font that a browser uses and some other calculations that i don't know. And that's what css resets are for, to makes all the differents browsers default behaviours to be the same!

Comment: @MattiaNocerino I added reset code to normalize the default font-size across browsers. The computed height should be consistent for all browsers now...

Comment: It's still different. On Firefox I get a 68px sized div.

Comment: I know this might sound stupid but, have you tried setting the font-size and line-height with pixels and not em?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a line height with a CSS unit (em or px, etc) means that the line height is computed (in this case, the line height becomes 19.2px) and then the *computed* value will inherit to the span. The span will therefore also have a line height of 19 (rounded) pixels rather than the 192 pixels you expect.

Solution: set the line height without a CSS unit. If you write `line-height:1.2` the inherited value of the line height will be what you want.

```css
div > span {
  font-size: 10em;
}
div {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Normalize the default font size */
body {
  font-size: 16px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Cat</span>
</div>
```

As for an explanation why the div itself doesn't become the same height (19px), this is because of the descender of the large text, which takes up space below the baseline. In your case, this is apparently 52px (it might be different for different fonts) causing the div to grow down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found the height of the `span` element is 184px instead of 192px..  Any idea about this?

Comment: By the way, it is still not clear to me how the `66px` is calculated.. Is it an undefined thing of CSS....

Comment: @hanfeisun I added an explanation of how the resulting div height is determined.